# Executing exe file in PowerShell Terminal fails silently

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with PowerShell Terminal error reporting on Windows 11.

I try to check if PHP was installed properly on the system. I know that VS redistributable was not installed yet, so my test should fail. If I use the old command prompt and type `php -v` it shows the correct error in a dialog box. So it is easy to solve.

However, if I use PowerShell Terminal and type `.\php.exe -v` then it just fails silently. I mean I got back the prompt without any error message or error dialog.

I don't want to write a script I just want a simple, manual test and get some feedback in the PowerShell Terminal.

Just to clarify: my problem is not how to solve the PHP-related installation issue. I have created the problem myself for testing purposes. My question is why PowerShell doesn't report any error.

Comment: Using php it is searching the path variable for the executable, but when you use .\php.exe it is using the executable in current folder.  Where is the file located?

Comment: The location is correct. If the location is not correct at least I get an error message.

Comment: If it's in add/remove programs, get-package should list it.

Comment: Try -a option.  See : https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php